# TCP message does not equal to what is sent in C#. How do I make it so it is?

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

### When I send the message to the client and I try to check it with an if statement it doesn't equal to what I sent from the server.

What I want to do is: I want to send the keyword (here it's poop) and check it with an if statement on the client part.
If it finds that keyword with the if statement I want to execute some code.

#### For example:

Client code:

```cs
try {
            TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");
            
            tcpclnt.Connect("127.0.0.1",8001);
            
            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
            
            Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();
                        
            ASCIIEncoding asen= new ASCIIEncoding();
            
            
            while(true)
            {
                byte[] bb=new byte[100];
                int k=stm.Read(bb,0,100);
                for (int i=0;i<k;i++)
                {
                    var msg = Convert.ToChar(bb[i]).ToString();
                    if(msg == "poop")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Poop executed.");
                    }
                }
            }
            
            
            
            
            
            
        }
        
        catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
        }
```

Server code (when the console reads my input I type "poop"):

```cs
try {
        IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
         

        TcpListener myList=new TcpListener(ipAd,8001);

        myList.Start();
        
        Console.WriteLine("The server is running at port 8001...");    
        Console.WriteLine("The local End point is  :" + 
                          myList.LocalEndpoint );
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.....");
        
        Socket s=myList.AcceptSocket();
        Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);
        
        
        
        

        ASCIIEncoding asen=new ASCIIEncoding();
        while(true)
        {
            
            Console.Write("Msg to send: ");
            var f = Console.ReadLine();
            s.Send(asen.GetBytes(f));
        }
        s.Close();
        myList.Stop();
            
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
    }
```

Comment: TCP/IP is streaming, so you can't rely on complete messages are received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you iterate over the byte array in which you wrote the received data. Therefore the `message` variable does always contain only one letter of your received message and is therefore never "poop" but "p", "o", "o", "p". To solve this issue you can use `System.Text.Encoding` to convert your byte array to a string:

```cs
byte[] bb = new byte[100];
int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);
var msg = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bb, 0, k);

if(msg == "poop")
{
   // Do something
}
```

An even better solution would be to write back your received data into a temporary array until a defined end of string signal is received and only convert the temporary array if you are sure that everything is received.

Comment: Hey thanks, it works (partially), when I send the poop message it spams the "Poop executed." in the console 4 times instead of once. If you can help me solve that I will mark it as a solution.

Comment: My guess is you have the `Console.WriteLine` call still inside of the loop? You can get rid of the loop.

Comment: Great and thank you sir, you helped me very much! :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help!